# String literal implicitly converted to basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, arm

I'm hoping someone might be able to explain why it seems like a string literal is being implicitly converted to basic_string:

```
void myFunc(const char* myArg)
{

}

myFunc("MyStringLiteral")
```

results in the following compilation error:

```
cannot convert 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for 
argument '1' to 'void myFunc(const char*)'
```

Any thoughts??

P.S. I am using the arm-none-eabi-g++ compiler

Comment: Could be a compiler-specific issue (it compiled just fine with normal g++). The obvious (but annoying) work-around is explicit casting.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal complete case that reproduces the issue?

Comment: For me this code compiles just fine with arm-none-eabi-g++... What are your compilation flags?

Comment: It would probably help to note what g++ version this is, where it came from (since the configuration, extra patches, etc. might matter) and how you're invoking it. A cursory look around suggests you may be compiling as some form of C++14.